# Averaging daily precipitation pcraster map stack for 10 years of data with python

Tags: python, raster

I have 3652 map in pcraster map stack type for daily precipitation value

```
pptn0000.001
pptn0000.002
...
pptn0003.652
```

I understand that there is a pcrcalc command but I'm lacking examples to do the mathematical operation on this type of map.
how can I average those maps in python and have one raster map as the output?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did this just now to get a 'climatological precipitation' from TRMM mission (17 years, 1998-2014).
  Python can read raster maps directly using pcraster library. For example:

```
    import os
    import fnmatch
    import subprocess
    from os import listdir
    from pcraster import *

    PrecDaily = '/home/someData/precipitation/pptn'
    OutSave = '/home/someData/precipitation/pptn/meanMap'
    TypeFile = 'pptn????.???'

    os.chdir(PrecDaily)
    PrecDailyFiles = []
    for iListFile in sorted(os.listdir('.')): 
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(iListFile, TypeFile):
            PrecDailyFiles.append(iListFile)
    n=len(PrecDailyFiles)

    FirstRasterMap = readmap(PrecDailyFiles[0])
    SUM = FirstRasterMap
    for iMeanRaster in xrange(1, n):
        PCRasterMap = readmap(PrecDailyFiles[iMeanRaster])
        SUM = SUM + PCRasterMap
    MEAN = SUM/n

    os.chdir(OutSave)
    report(MEAN, 'pptn_mean.map')
```

Comment: thank you @Raf I find it really helpful and I manage to work it for my recharge estimates as well, thanks